# bootstrap: four span3-thumbnails in responsive span12

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

We stacked a `span12`- in a `span8`-container and tried placing four thumbnails in a row. Sadly the last `<li>` breaks to next line although screensize would allow that all four thumbnails fit in a row.

Same behaviour with other combinations like 6x `span2` ...

I build a small fiddle showing this behaviour:
http://jsfiddle.net/PnWjT/

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your layout is that you're improperly stacking your bootstrap classes and that's why your layout is not acting the way you want it to.

Take this for example:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="container-fluid"> .. </div>
</div>
```

Here you are trying to stack a fluid container div, `.container-fluid`, within a fixed container div, `.container`, and thus the cancelling out the `.container-fluid` div. These two containment divs were meant to be used to encapsulate the layout that you want and not to stack each other up, so only use one.

Another issue with your stacks is the following:

```
<div class="span8">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                 ......
```

Here you are stacking a `span12` div (width 100% within the `.row-fluid` container) div within a `span8` div (width 65.812% within `.row-fluid`) and thus your content is being pushed to the right because your `span12` div is overflowing the smaller container `span8` div and its not properly adjusting to resize changes because of it. You are supposed to stack the `span` divs  accordingly to their widths, e.g. `span12/2 = span6, span4*2 = span8, span5 + span5 = span10`, etc...

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PnWjT/1/) with the proper stack reworked. Notice how the sidebar lays on a `span4` div and the content on a `span8`, `span4 + span8 = span12`, you can't go any higher than `span12` unless you create your own class.

Comment: _Nesting with fluid grids is a bit different: the number of nested columns doesn't need to match the parent. Instead, your columns are reset at each level because each row takes up 100% of the parent column._ it says on the [bootstrap-docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) or am I missing something here?!

Comment: @Seybsen The columns reset at each level, meaning that once you start resizing your browser each row starts to take up 100% of the width of the parent, but they are still susceptible to the parents width when the browser is fullscreen. That is what makes them `fluid`.

Comment: @AndresIlich What I'm taking away from this is that in a fluid layout each level needs to add up to 12.  Is that correct?

Comment: @CrimsonChin yes, that is correct, you can have as many grid elements within a row as long as they add up to 12, so you can combine multiple grid `.spanX` and as long as they total 12 they will fit just fine.